# DLP tag renaming

Tags: discussion, retagging

Over on superuser we have a tag conflict.

*[DLP](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dlp)* is used for both for [DLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Light_Processing) & [DLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Loss_Prevention)

Since it's only three questions it would be easy to retag them, but I don't know what tags I should use.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand one or both of them from their acronyms: `digital-light-processing` and `data-loss-prevention`.  I'd certainly do it for the latter since it's not particularly common in usage.  Perhaps, you could replace the latter with `backups` -- you might want to ask @Jeff about this.  :-)

Comment: Yeah. Shouldn't even be a problem to do this manually as there are a whopping **3** questions tagged `dlp`! :-)

Answer (score 2):

DLP is *rarely* expanded when referencing the light processing technology, and few people even know what the acronym means.  They do, however, know what DLP refers to in terms of projectors, TVs, etc.

Data Loss Prevention is ONLY ever abbreviated to DLP in literature after it's been defined once - everyone knows the full name, but the acronym isn't used without a definition first.

Further, anyone searching for data loss prevention isn't going to use the acronym to find related material - they will be swamped with projector information.

Therefore if Data Loss Prevention doesn't have a better term ('backup' doesn't exactly cover it - backup is a subset of Data Loss Prevention) then the tag should be `data-loss-prevention`

`DLP` should continue to be used to the refer to the light processing technology used in projectors, etc.

Comment: @Pollyanna -- to be fair, I did add a smiley to indicate the joke.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Aw, but I'm *sure* Jeff wants to be consulted on this!